# Having each enum element associated with a unique Vector value

Tags: haskell, types, enums, enumeration

I thought about making a Direction data type and I'd like to have each element associated with a 3d Vector indicating the x, y and z value of the direction. Up, for instance, would have the value 0 1 0. What is a good way to do this?

```
data Direction = None | Up | Right | Down | Left | Above | Below deriving (Enum)
```

Is doing as below really the best way?:

```
direction :: Direction -> Point3
direction Up               = Point3 0    1    0
direction GameEngine.Right = Point3 1    0    0
direction Down             = Point3 0    (-1) 0
direction GameEngine.Left  = Point3 (-1) 0    0
direction Above            = Point3 0    0    1
direction Below            = Point3 0    0    (-1)
direction None             = Point3 0    0    0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also, `Left` and `Right` are already taken by `Either` which could cause some inconvenience.

Comment: Up refers to a Vector x y z of 0 1 0, white Above refers to a vector of 0 0 1. In a 2D game with floors in which the floor value has the z axis.

Comment: Right, I was thinking in 2D. I would say that, if you want a function like `direction`, the best way is probably to write the cases out like that.

Comment: `Array Direction Point3`.

Comment: That looks fine to me, although in a code review I'd recommend a different name than `direction`. Maybe `toPoint3` or something.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m), you can use an Array.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
import Data.Array
import Prelude hiding (Left, Right, abs)

data Direction = None | Above | Below | Up | Down | Right | Left deriving (Enum, Ord, Eq, Ix)

-- helper function for finding absolute value of Point3
abs (Point3 x y z) = sqrt $ fromIntegral $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2

-- written long way using do-notation
dir :: Array Direction Point3
dir = listArray (None, Left) states
  where
    moves = [0, 1, -1]
    states :: [Point3]
    states = do
      x <- moves
      y <- moves
      z <- moves
      let point = Point3 x y z
      guard $ abs point <= 1
      return point

-- written short way using list-comprehension
dir :: Array Direction Point3
dir = listArray (None,Left) [p |
    x <- m, y <- m, z <- m,
    let p = Point3 x y z,
    abs p <= 1
  ] where m = [0, 1, -1]
```

Indexing into the array by `Direction` will give you a `Point3`.

```
>>> dir ! Above
Point3 0 0 1
```

This will give you a slight performance advantage over a function because you will have permanent cache of pre-constructed `Point3`s and hence, will not cause any allocation.

The other bonus is that the code is pretty neat!

The disadvantage is that it requires Direction to be Ord, Eq and Ix.